# How do I force Chrome DevTools Audits to use desktop (fullscreen) emulation?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, pagespeed, lighthouse

I want to run a performance audit of my website for: desktop, without throttling network, without throttling CPU.

I'm using Google Chrome's DevTools's Audits tab and selecting the following options:

- Device: Desktop
- Audits: Performance
- Throttling: No throttling
- Clear storage (checked)

My chrome version:

```
Google Chrome is up to date
Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

According to the "Audits" tab, my Lighthouse version in Chrome is `3.2.0`

After clicking `Run audits` button, the report is generated, and contains the following *Runtime settings*:

```
URL: https://example.com/
Fetch time: Dec 15, 2018, 11:18 PM PST
Device: Emulated Nexus 5X
Network throttling: 150 ms TCP RTT, 1,638.4 Kbps throughput (Simulated)
CPU throttling: 4x slowdown (Simulated)
User agent (host): Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36
User agent (network): Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3559.0 Mobile Safari/537.36
CPU/Memory Power: 998
```

So how do I **force** my settings to be used so I can correctly audit for desktop?

**EDIT:** Verified upstream as Chrome bug:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914387

Answer (score 1):

It appears this is a Google Chrome bug, see below for quotes and reference:

```
We've found the culprit, but it'll require a Chrome-side fix.

Note that it's not just Mobile/Desktop, but the throttling settings and clear storage options are also being ignored at the moment which would explain all of the performance score differences.
-- patrickhulce, paulirish
```

Ref: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/6772#issuecomment-446626154

Upstream bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=914387

```
Verified the fix on Mac 10.12.6, Windows-10 & Ubuntu 17.10 on Chrome version #73.0.3640.0 as per the comment#0
```

Approved for Chrome M72 branch, 3626